# what's the matter of my C cord?(about struct array pointer)

Tags: c

first, I defined one struct.

```
struct book_record{
char book_name[52];
char publisher_name[32];
char name[32];
int publishing_year;
int page;
```

};

and I made a cord like this.

```
 FILE* book_data = fopen("book.txt", "rt"); 
FILE* book_file = fopen("book2.txt","wt"); 
int input, i, j;
fscanf(book_data, "%d", &input);
struct book_record *m[input];

for(i=0; i<input; i++){
    m[i] = (struct book_record *)malloc(sizeof(struct book_record));
}

enter
```

I don't feel this cord have problem. but my teacher said me that this cord have big problem.
teacher says because "input" is not initialized, struct record *m[input] has an error.
but I think I clearly declare input by 'fscanf' before *m[input].
I can't understand my teacher's said. Help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a sidenote: It is called *code*, not *cord* .

Comment: You do not check return type of `fscanf`. What happens if it returns `0` or `EOF`? How large will your array `m[input]` be then?

Comment: In the code you've shown if the file fails to open or the `fscanf` call fails you have a problem but don't know it. You should always check to be sure file pointers are not NULL before using them and always check the return value of functions like `fscanf`.

Comment: About wording: *Declaring* a variable does not reserve any memory nor does it provide a defined value. You are *defining* your variable `input` but without an initializer this does not provide any defined value. That is what your teacher meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
int input, i, j;
```

At this point, none of `input`, `i`, or `j` have any particular value; their contents are *indeterminate*.

Yes, you are attempting to read a value for `input` before using it:

```
fscanf(book_data, "%d", &input);
struct book_record *m[input];
```

but the `fscanf` operation can fail - if the first character in the `book_data` stream isn't a decimal digit or if there's a problem with the stream, then `fscanf` won't assign anything to `input` and it will still have that indeterminate value (which could be positive, negative, zero, very large, etc.).

`fscanf` returns the number of items successfully converted and assigned or `EOF` if it sees an end-of-file or error - in this case, you're expecting to read 1 item, so `fscanf` should return 1 on success.  You should check that return value before using `input`:

```
if ( fscanf( book_data, "%d", &input ) != 1 )
{
  fputs( "Error reading input from book_data, exiting\n", stderr );
  exit( 0 );
}

struct book_record *m[input];
```

If for any reason that `fscanf` operation fails, we'll exit the program before trying to use `input`.

You should also make sure the `fopen` calls succeed as well before trying to use those streams:

```
FILE* book_data = fopen("book.txt", "rt"); 
if ( !book_data )
{
  fputs( "Could not open book.txt, exiting...\n", stderr );
  exit( 0 );
}

FILE* book_file = fopen("book2.txt","wt"); 
if ( !book_file )
{
  fputs( "Could not open book2.txt, exiting...\n", stderr );
  fclose( book_data ); 
  exit( 0 );
}
```